# Foreground job from invoke-command -asjob

Tags: powershell

Let’s say I have a really long job that I start with invoke-command as follows:

```
$s = New-PSSession -Computer mycomp

Invoke-command -session $s -file myprofile.ps1

$j = invoke-command -asjob -Session $s -File ./reallylongtime.ps1

Wait-job $j
Receive-job $j
```

Is there a way to reattach the job $j as a foreground job and watch its terminal output in real-time?  Currently, I’m waiting for the job to finish and then outputting the job terminal output all at once with receive-job.

Also, I don’t want to just call  “invoke-command -computer”
I need this to work with new-pssession instead.

Answer (score 0):

Answer, poll receive-job until job is finished…

```
while ($j.State -eq 'Running' -and $j.HasMoreData) {
    Receive-Job $j
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 200
}
```

Everytime you call receive-job in the loop it will display new output from the running job.